# Create CSS Hover Image in Wordpress

Tags: css, hover

I have a site [here](http://azeverything.com/people)...

When you look at this page, you'll see an image of a comment bubble...

**Here's the CSS attached to that comment bubble...**

```
#content .postmetadata .comments {
 background-image:url(images/comment.png);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 position:absolute;
 bottom:8px;
 height:25px;
 *bottom:18px;
 margin-left:8px;
}
```

What I'm trying to do is, by default have the image that you see there... (it's black with about 50% opacity).

When you hover over it, the image turns red, but keeps the background transparent, so it's only the bubble that changes color.

I have the red image ready, or is that something I can do with CSS?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Please read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Creating a CSS hover state image in Wordpress seems important to me. How do I know what's going to go beyond my (the original poster) scope and help others. That's why I tried to keep this as general as possible. If you think it should be edited to reflect a more general question, please do so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   #content .postmetadata .comments:hover {
   background-image:url(images/yourredimage.png);
   background-repeat:no-repeat; position:absolute; bottom:8px;
   height:25px;
   *bottom:18px;
   margin-left:8px;
   }
```

Comment: You nailed it! I thought this would be more difficult in Wordpress, but it doesn't appear to be... I have to stop thinking too far into things...

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to do what I have on my site for my social media links.

I have it set up as a sprite:
http://michelenarup.com/wp-content/themes/Portfolio/images/social.png

And the code will change the background position for the hover state:

```
    #facebook{background-position: -100px 0px; float:left; height:50px; width:50px; padding:0; background-image: url('../images/social.png'); margin-bottom: 10px;}
    a#facebook:hover{background-position: -100px -50px; outline:none;}
```

---edit---

```
    a.comments {
     background-image:url(images/comment.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:8px;
     height:25px;
     *bottom:18px;
     margin-left:8px;
    }


    a.comments:hover {
     background-image:url(images/comment-hover.png);
     background-repeat:no-repeat;
     position:absolute;
     bottom:8px;
     height:25px;
     *bottom:18px;
     margin-left:8px;
    }
```

Comment: For the purpose of helping this user, it's not necessary to use a sprite - you can just assign a hover state image, but I do agree a sprite is a perfectly good way of going about this.

Comment: It would be the same as the code for the sprite. Only instead of having to set a background position, just put a different background image for the :hover state

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin to do this. Check it out [wp-visual-slide-box-builder](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-visual-slidebox-builder/)